# Issue with php image search system

Tags: php

i have made an image search system. Each image has been named like this tag1_tag2_tag3_tag4.jpg searching for tag1 does not work but for all the others it does. Is this an issue with strpos or am i missing something?

Code:

```
                $images = glob($filedir."*.{jpg,JPG,png,PNG,gif,GIF}",GLOB_BRACE);
                if (empty($images))
                {
                    echo '<p>Something went wrong with the image retrieval!</p>';
                }
                else
                {
                    foreach($images as $image)
                    {
                        $filename = pathinfo($image, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
                        $filename = str_replace("_","",$filename);
                        if (strpos($filename, $query))
                        {
                            echo '<a href="'.$image.'"><img src="'.getThumb($image).'"/></a>';
                        }
                    }
```

Comment: Hard to say; you've a `getThumb()` function we don't know about; relevance? Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything.

Comment: so you have no pics wit hthe same tag? this does not seem like the best approach

Comment: @Fred-ii- I can search for tag2-3-4-5-6 so on, but not nr.1 getThumb() finds an image based upon the filename. It works.

Comment: if i add a letter to the start of the filename then it works.

Comment: *Another happy ending*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`strpos()` returns the position. If it finds it at the zero'th position then it returns zero. But you are using it as a boolean and zero is false.

Instead compare with `!==`:

```
if (strpos($filename, $query) !== false)
```

Comment: unfortunately this does not solve my issue. I tried the code, and it made not change.

Comment: you are onto something here. if i add any letter to the start of the file, and name it ex aname and search for name then i get a result. i will not get an result if the filename is just name.

Comment: Can you put your modified code either in your question above (edited) or else in a pastebin somewhere?

Comment: Never mind - I had my logic reversed. Try it now, with the !==

Comment: Works now. Thank´s. i really had my head twisted on this one.